# Replace � character in string

Tags: php, unicode

I scrape one website via PHP. In the page source there is something like this:

```
11.8�20.5�26.8"
```

How I can identify this character via PHP and replace it by some other sign?

I tried this but it doesn't work good, PHP doesnt allow me to copy this character �:

```
$description = trim(str_replace("�","",$description));
```

Comment: is your PHP file UTF-8?

Comment: how do you mean? im scraping this source code from the internet?

Comment: Your PHP script. Open it in your IDE/editor. What character encoding is it? If it is not UTF-8, and the remote resource IS UTF-8, you will get encoding issues like this. UTF-8 all the things!

Comment: On the converse side, if you ARE in UTF-8, then the remote guys are in the wrong, in which case use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: It shows me this character ×
But when i open it in the browser again its again�

Comment: what IDE do you use? Does your HTML have meta charset=utf-8?

Comment: i use notepad++

Comment: ok. what does it say in the ecoding menu?

Comment: 11.8×20.5×26.8&quot;

Comment: No it doesn't. Notepad ++ Encoding menu has options like Encode in ANSI. Encode in UTF-8. etc. What encoding is your script written in?

Comment: UTF-8.................

Comment: this remote resource, is IT in UTF-8?

Comment: i dont know that, how i can check?

Comment: is it publicly accessible? If so, browse, view source, check meta tag for character encoding

Comment: it looks the same in the source code: �

Comment: Then it's THEIR mistake, and the answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reported × character which is dec 215 or hex D7

Try this:

```
$replacement = 'x'; // I mean letter 'x' (or use any other character)

$description = preg_replace('/[\xD7]/', $replacement, $description);
```

Comment: and you expect him to do that for every character outwith the encoding he is in?

Comment: no, only this one, in general you can extend or use some code to replace range of unicode characters

Comment: since I have a problem only for this one character, this solution helped me, I don't know is this the best answer, but thanks

Comment: @delboy1978uk but if you want to replace to a particular character, you have to specify if for any unicode value! do you have any other solution?

Comment: It'll work, until the next dodgy letter appears. Yes, the better solution is to convert the encoding to UTF8 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php.

Comment: @delboy1978uk right, if you just want to remove "bad" character. If you want to replace it to a particular one, you have no choice rather than specify replacement for each character

Comment: Yes but thats just hacking bad input, instead of passing in valid data in the first place. The correct answer is always valid input.

Comment: agree, this is hacking bad input because it's bad and you have to hack it :-) maybe you can really fix that with encoding settings conversion, maybe not, but this method always works; this is not a big problem, but if you ever worked with AWS search services building indexes out of HTML files, you met a similar problem with control characters (mostly from x01-x1F), a big pain until you figure that out and the only method works is the one I proposed to this question

Comment: OP says the source of the remote has the bad character, so it's their mistake and therefore yours is indeed the only solution in this instance ;-)

Comment: @delboy1978uk, A programmer never can expect an end user to input a valid data. they always need to be standing on their toe, meaning you need to check and validate every single piece of data external to your code, in this case scrapped website. In some cases you need to log the data to investigate why the issue was caused in first place, however you cannot log data the same way it is, it might harm your system (e.g. the control code that activated firmware update on some WD hard disks few years back). You need to replace those characters to unharmful codes e.g. their hex representation.

Comment: @AnatoliyR , I would go with [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr) to replace multiple character at once. my case was control characters (below 0\x1F)